# Gitlab CI got error selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH when I running my simple pro

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, gitlab-ci, python-unittest

I'm just learning selenium using python in gitlab CI, i wanna try to run my simple project, but i got error "Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH".

this is my python script :

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

    class GoogleTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
     
        def setUp(self):
            self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
            self.addCleanup(self.browser.quit)
    
        def testPageTitle(self):
            self.browser.get('http://www.google.com')
            self.assertIn('Google', self.browser.title)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

and this is my  .gitlab-ci.yml script

```
image: "python:3.7" run_test:   services:
    - selenium/standalone-chrome   before_script:
    - python -V
    - python3 -m pip install pytest
    - python3 -m pip install selenium pytest
    - python3 -m pip install webdriver_manager
    - python3 -m pip install allure-pytest   script:
    - python test_sele_python.py   tags:
    - python3-alpine
```

when i run the pipeline a got error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX7rU.png)

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the webdriver.Chrome function you need to make sure you add a PATH to a chromedriver. So download a chromedriver with the current version of your chrome and add it into the function. The new code should look like this.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

    class GoogleTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
     
        def setUp(self):
            self.browser = webdriver.Chrome("/PATH/TO/CHROMEDRIVER.EXE")
            self.addCleanup(self.browser.quit)
    
        def testPageTitle(self):
            self.browser.get('http://www.google.com')
            self.assertIn('Google', self.browser.title)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```